# sfinae for g++ 4.1.2

Tags: gcc, g++, sfinae, typename

I have a problem with SFINAE with G++ 4.1.2.

The following code works properly for 4.6:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Test
{
public:
    int x;
};

template <typename T> 
inline T f(T v) { return v;}                // Definition #2

template <typename T> 
inline typename T::x f(T v) { return v.x; } // Definition #1

int main()
{
Test t;
t.x = 100;

    printf("Test.x = %d\n", f(t));
    printf("int = %d\n", f(10));
}
```

Naturally, the output is:

```
Test.x = 100
int = 10
```

I need something like to this to work on g++ 4.1.2, any ideas ? Frankly, I don't understand how there could be so much difference between these two compilers!

Or if you have an alternative for it, that would be great. Something with templates! Or MACROS...

Comment: GCC 4.1.2 was released on February 13, **2007**; GCC 4.6.0 in **2011**. How could you _not_ expect differences?

Comment: with so much difference... I would expect it to be called 5.X, not 4.6... maybe that's just me. Also, I just hate being stuck with 4.1.2, even new product release for 2013 are still made with that... it's a bit sad!

Comment: This seems to work with **4.1.3**.

Comment: damn... so it's really just 4.1.2 that is annoying like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved a part of my problem...

But for this case here, it should be `template<class T>` and not `template<typename T>`...

So just an half Hi-Five to myself. But for the second part, I used another approach, it was annoying to do, but it worked.

Comment: What was your solution? I'm encountering a similar problem with SFINAE and 4.1.2.
(Also, out of curiosity, why are you using 4.1.2? Maya?)